# Targeting elements way up the tree

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm needing to grab a specific element. I have an event that triggers when I click the `a` tag. I'm having trouble reaching it since I can only effect the `ul` that the a tag is inside. The element I want to select has a class of `target`. The obvious answer is to select `target`, but there are multiple target classes. My question is how do I target the element I want. Below is the code.

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="target">
        Here is the div that I want to target. But I can't target it.
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <a>Clicking here triggers the event.</a>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(a).parentsUntil('#section').children(':gt(0)').children(':gt(2)').css('color','red');
</script>
```

Comment: `$('a').parents('#section').find('#target').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks. I got it to work. Post it as the answer and you will get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').parents('#section').find('#target').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to enclose your code in DOM Ready Handler..

```
$(function() {
    // Your code Here
});
```

Secondly your selector is wrong

Supposed to be `$('a')`    instead of `$(a)`

Try this code

```
$(this).closest('div').prev('#target').css('color', 'red');
```

OR

```
$('a').parents('#section').find('#target').css('color', 'red');
```

**[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6DuTn/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function() {

        $(this).closest('div').prev('#target').css('color', 'red');
    });
});​
```

Comment: Dom ready isn't necessary since it works. Thanks for the selector syntax, it was right in my code but when I posted it on here I forgot to add the single quotation marks. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @jason328 .. It is not necessary since you have included your script after the HTML elements, but I feel it is a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the demo and explanations!